# Selenium didnt record my installed extension's objects

Tags: java, selenium

I have my custom developed extension which installed in Mozilla browser.  When I tried to write selenium test case for recording script for my extension, it does not get recorded in script.

Comment: check your Firefox profile, and see if it's the one loaded by Selenium. Do you have an explicit call on the Profile you want in the configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to record and replay a Firefox Extension instead of a web application you should have a look at Mozmill